# Network issues after enabling IPv6 on the router

Tags: networking, internet

I've got an issue on all Ubuntu based machines on my network after enabling IPv6 on the router. All Windows 10 machines, android phones, iphones work fine, so I suspect the issue is with Ubuntu.

The reason I enabled IPv6 on the router is because I churned to a new ISP which uses a dual stack network with CGNAT, so no port forwarding on IPv4.

I first noticed the issue when browsing. I can browse, but can't log into sites like reddit on my Ubuntu machine. I can ping reddit.com

```
~ ❯ ping -c 4 reddit.com
PING reddit.com (151.101.65.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.65.140 (151.101.65.140): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=7.01 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.140 (151.101.65.140): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=7.63 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.140 (151.101.65.140): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=7.22 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.65.140 (151.101.65.140): icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=7.07 ms

--- reddit.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.008/7.232/7.634/0.243 ms
```

The big problem is I use docker a fair bit. I can't even pull docker images. I can't even ping docker.io.

```
~ ❯ docker --log-level debug pull python:3.8-slim
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.8-slim: read tcp 10.1.1.32:45788->54.85.107.53:443: read: connection timed out

~  1 ❯ ping -c 4 docker.io
PING docker.io (3.227.177.167) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- docker.io ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3068ms
```

This makes me think it's a DNS issue. I use a Pi-hole as a DNS server on my network. I've tried various combinations of configurations with and without the Pi-hole as my DNS server. The windows devices have no problem using any of the DNS servers. The lack of progress then makes me think it's not a DNS issue.

My wife reports the same browsing issues on her Ubuntu laptop.

What I've tried:

- [x] googling
- [x] tried using google's DNS
- [x] tried using ISP's DNS
- [x] tried auto configurations
- [x] tried static IP configs (preferred)
- [x] licking my elbow
- [ ] the thing that is going to fix it

Any ideas?

Further information:

```
~ ❯ dig google.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com A
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45814
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             266     IN      A       142.250.66.206

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 29 21:14:50 AWST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55


~ ❯ dig google.com AAAA

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com AAAA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5462
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             202     IN      AAAA    2404:6800:4006:809::200e

;; Query time: 16 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 29 21:14:52 AWST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 67


~ ❯ ip route
default via 10.1.1.1 dev enp39s0 proto static metric 100
10.1.1.0/24 dev enp39s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.32 metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-a10d1f1adfd2 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-824d593daae1 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
192.168.39.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.39.1 linkdown
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown

~ ❯ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2400:ec40:1012:1a00::/64 dev enp39s0 proto ra metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp39s0 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
default via fe80::e6f4:c6ff:fe04:8841 dev enp39s0 proto ra metric 100 pref low

~ ❯ ping6 -c 4 google.com
PING google.com(syd09s15-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:809::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from syd09s15-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:809::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=120 time=55.8 ms
64 bytes from syd09s15-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:809::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=120 time=52.7 ms
64 bytes from syd09s15-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:809::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=120 time=53.0 ms
64 bytes from syd09s15-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4006:809::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=120 time=51.5 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 51.481/53.265/55.825/1.588 ms

~ ❯ systemd-resolve --status enp39s0
Link 2 (enp39s0)
Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
DNSOverTLS setting: no
DNSSEC setting: no
DNSSEC supported: no
Current DNS Server: 10.1.1.1
DNS Servers: 10.1.1.12
10.1.1.1
DNS Domain: ~.
```

All my devices with static IP have always had DNS set as 10.1.1.12, 10.1.1.1.
The router is at 10.1.1.1 which has the Pi-hole set as the DNS with fallback to 1.1.1.1. The Pi-hole is at 10.1.1.12.
So the preference order is Pi-hole (-> 9.9.9.9, 1.1.1.1), router (-> pi-hole, 1.1.1.1).
The Pi-hole is configured with IPv6 and is confirmed as working by the `ping6` result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the router MTU auto configured to 1492, which is normal for PPPoE. However, it doesn't have enough space for the IPv6 header.

Refer to [Wikipedia article on MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit#MTUs_for_common_media).

Setting the router MTU to 1452 resolved all issues - even Netflix works on the TV now.